# permission denied for jmeter.bat while executing jmeter using robotframework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-4.0

while trying to execute  jmeter file using robotframework  getting below error,

### PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/sadha/Documents/jmeter.bat'

TC2 jmeter                                                            | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed

I am using [Robot Framework JMeter Library](https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/JMeterLib.html) for the execution.eventhough i have enabeled read/write  permission i am still getting this error,

Below is the robot keyword used for execution,

Run Jmeter      /home/sadha/Documents/jmeter.bat    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx  /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl

Comment: In linux you should call jmeter.sh

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much ..issue resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to call [jmeter.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh) or [jmeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter), the .bat file is for Windows
2. You might also need to make the file executable using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command like:

   ```
   chmod +x /home/sadha/Documents/jmeter.sh
   ```

More information:

- [Apache JMeter - Get Started - CLI Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)